# number of rows in database - prepared statements - php

Tags: php, mysqli

I can't seem to work out how to retrieve number of rows from the database using my query, whenever I run the query It just returns zero even though it's in my database

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$hash = password_verify($password, $passwordcheck);

if($stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT username, email, password FROM users WHERE (username = ? OR email = ?) AND password = ?"))
{

    $stmt -> bind_param("sss", $username, $username, $hash);
    $stmt -> execute();

    $stmt -> bind_result($checkedUsername, $checkedEmail, $checkedPassword);

    $stmt -> fetch();
    $numberofrows = $stmt->num_rows;

    $stmt -> close();
}
echo '# rows: '.$numberofrows;
```

Can anyone give me any hints? Can't see to wrap my head around it, thanks.

Btw, the $hash has already been queried prior to this statement.

Comment: `password_verify` doesn't return a hash, but a boolean.

Comment: @jeff I just narrowed the query down to just the username and it still returns 0

Comment: what db interface is that?

Comment: add `$stmt->store_result();` after `execute()`. @stepho

Comment: ^ I edited that above ^ made a typo. should have been "after" and not "before". I'll delete this shortly. reload that comment @stepho

Comment: @Fred Wow I actually tried that earlier on an off chance, turns out I must have put it in the wrong place because worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: As you have not yet queried the database what does this `$hash = password_verify($password, $passwordcheck);` do or what do you expect it to do.

Comment: As I assume you have used `password_hash()` on the password you store in the database. Then you should not be using it in a search criteria. Re-hashing the same string **will not generate the same hash using `password_hash()`** as it will use a different SALT each time its run Thats why its the recommended hashing tool

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah, slightly stuck, I queried the password in the database and have used if ($hash == 0) {$error['username'] = 'Password wrong';}. Didn't realise it only outputted a true or false statement previously so left it out of the num_rows statement.

Comment: I added a community wiki answer. anyone can edit/add to it if they want

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ignore my last comment, my error statement was hidden so I thought It wasn't working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki:

add `$stmt->store_result();` after your `execute()`

Comment: anyone's welcome to edit/add to this; I don't want rep from this

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you have used password_hash() on the password you store in the database. Then you should not be using it in a search criteria. Re-hashing the same string will not generate the same hash using password_hash() as it will use a different SALT each time its run Thats why its the recommended hashing tool.

So you need to do something like this

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, email, password 
                        FROM users WHERE (username = ? OR email = ?)") 
if($stmt) {

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $username);
    $stmt->execute();

    // As per @fred-ii- comment
    $stmt->store_result();

    $stmt->bind_result($checkedUsername, $checkedEmail, $checkedPassword);

    $stmt->fetch();

    echo '# rows: ' . $stmt->num_rows;

    if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $checkedPassword) ) {
        // password is correct
    } else {
        // password is NOT correct
    }

    $stmt -> close();
}
```